# Как обратиться к элементу вектора в ассемблерной вставке?

Tags: ассемблер, visual-studio-2012, c++

Как обратиться к элементу вектора в ассемблерной вставке c++ (vs2012)?

```
int m = 1000;

std::vector<int> v(m + 1, 1);

__asm
{
  ???
}
```

Comment: Можно до ассемблерной вставки записать в переменную указатель на первый элемент и работать с ним как с указателем на начало обычного массива int.

Answer (score 2):

В с++ коде получить указатель на первый элемент вектора

```
 void * firstItem = &v[0];
```

Дальше в ассемблере типа

```
mov eax, firstItem  
add eax, позиция в векторе * 4
```

---

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR [eax] - получить в eax значение
```

или

```
mov DWORD PTR [eax], 10 - записать значение в вектор
```

Answer (score 0):

имя вектора совпадает с именем первой переменной вектора

```
mov eax, v  // первая переменная
mov ebx, [v + 4] // + 4 это размер int в x32
```